# Inheritance of the FORM class as per MSDN documentation

Tags: vb.net

Does the following image (from MSDN Documentation) mean that class FORM inherits ContainerControl which has been derived from ScrollableControl which in turn inherits from CONTROL and so on? Is this understanding correct?

[image]

And does the below image (also from MSDN documentation) gives the classes that are derived from the FORM class?

[image]

The MSDN link that I am referring to is: [MSDN DOCUMENTATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know using images on SO is discouraged. But in this case, this grab from Visual Studio's *Object Explorer* provides the complete `Form` inheritance picture:

[image]

So the answer to the first part of your question is "Yes".

You can use *Object Explorer* to check the inheritance of any class but I don't think you can get a "reverse inheritance" snapshot like the one above, showing all classes inherited from a given class, though I could be wrong about that.